# Why do my Publishing Pages allow editors to publish even though they are not in the approvers group

Tags: 2013, publishing-page, publishing

The content authors have edited (*not contribute, or approve*) permissions.

Someone the publish button under the publish tab is enabled allowing them to publish. Once published the unpublish button is disabled. I thought they have to be in the approvers group in order to publish.

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should distinguish between two permission levels

- **Editors** should edit the document then send it for approval
- **Publisher** should review and publish the document and should be added to approval Group.

You can also [create your custom Permission level](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-permission-levels-83bf9b0d-877c-42b1-94c6-5eb81ee97a48) that match your requirements

Comment: So basically, I've given authors the "Edit" permission, and only have myself with the "Approver" permission.  The idea is that I would be the final approver and be able to publish. But these editors are also able to publish.